# Discrepancy between Search Console and Structured Data Testing Tool

Tags: seo, google-search-console, structured-data

I have 200+ errors flagging in Search Console > Search Appearance > Structured Data

These are all `hentry` errors that say 'Missing:updated'.
When testing live in the Structure Data Testing Tool, no errors appear.

The code has not changed since the last detected date.

I know that to fix this I would just add the updated property but, is Search Console unreliable/out of date that I can just ignore if all appears fine in the testing tool?

Comment: And how long have you waited for Webmaster Tools to reflect changes? Since obviously at some point your WordPress template used HENTRY incorrectly. Since resolving that issue it can take several months for Google to reflect the changes in Webmaster Tools, this is because Google WMT is not realtime but more so because Googlebot has to recrawl those pages, unless your site has good authority with constant crawling then it will take several weeks to months to update. Stale pages will take much longer than those that get updated from time to time, for example frontpage, blog pages etc.

Comment: Ah I see, the pages are blog posts that do not get updated as often as other areas of the site. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you should trust the [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) from Google over Google Search Console (GSC).

I once had 11m+ pages receive the structured data error in GSC.

It took 5 months for GSC to catch up (after we fixed the error).